# Count generated random number by each time clicking a button

Tags: java, swing, random, sum, jbutton

I have a java application which generates random numbers between 1-11 each time I click on a button, and my problem is i want to sum the generated nubmers each time I click on the button, for example if I click on the button three times then I want the sum of all the three random numbers which was created each time by clicking the button.
Sorry for my bad english, and I would be very thanful for any help.

Here is my code:

```
  public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private static JFrame frame;
private static JPanel p;
private static JButton b;
private static JButton choose;
private static JLabel random;
private static JLabel sumRandom;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game bl= new Game();
    bl.gui();


}
public void gui(){
    frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800, 500);
    frame.setLocation(500, 200);
    frame.setTitle("Blackjack");


    p= new JPanel();
    p.setLayout(null);
    p.setBackground(Color.GRAY);


    b = new JButton("Start play");
    b.setBounds(450, 50, 200, 50);

    b.addActionListener(this);

    choose= new JButton("choose");
    choose.setBounds(100, 50, 200, 50);
    choose.addActionListener(this);

    random= new JLabel("");
    random.setBounds(200, 150, 200, 50);

    sumRandom= new JLabel("");
    sumRandom.setBounds(30, 150, 200, 50);
    //text.setText();
    p.add(sumRandom);
    p.add(random);
    p.add(b);
    frame.add(p);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    if(e.getSource()== b){

        p.add(choose);
        b.setEnabled(false);
    }
    if(e.getSource()== choose){
        int randomNumbers = (int )(Math.random() * 11 + 1);
        random.setText(String.valueOf(random));
        int sum= randomNumbers++;
        sumRandom.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

What's problem? Add new int field to your class. Then sum the random number generated in actionPerformed method with it.

Answer (score 0):

create your sum variable as an instance variable or a static variable, when the random number is generated simply put:

```
sum += randomNumbers
```

Comment: Globally....? there is no such thing in java.. if you consider a static variable of a class global then you are wrong too... cuz when the class in unloaded u get into a problem. Redefine your answer. what you mean is an instance variable or a static variable that can be accessed by all the methods in the class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with

```
int sum= randomNumbers++;
```

Like Stanislav said, you'll want to grab the current sum and add to it. You can do this either using an int field and something like `sum = currentSum + randomNumbers;` or by parsing the text that's currently on `sumRandom`:

```
int currentSum = Integer.parseInt(sumRandom.getText());
currentSum += randomNumbers;
sumRandom.setText(String.valueOf(currentSum));
```

Of course, this latter approach should only be used if you're not setting the text of `sumRandom` anywhere else, and the former is a little cleaner, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Add a field to sum the value of the card. Make sure you have a mechanism, perhaps in start play button, to reset the value of the field once a new hand is dealt.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable to hold your sum,

```
public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JPanel p;
    private static JButton b;
    private static JButton choose;
    private static JLabel random;
    private static JLabel sumRandom;
    private static int sumRandomNumbers; //declare sum
```

Initialize it,

```
    private void sumRandomNumbersInit() { sumRandomNumbers=0; }
```

Report it,

```
    public int sumRandomNumbersget() { return sumRandomNumbers; }
```

Initialize it,

```
public void gui(){
    //...
    sumRandomNumbersInit();
    //...
}
```

Add each generated random number to sumRandomNumbers

```
if(e.getSource()== choose){
    int randomNumbers = (int )(Math.random() * 11 + 1);
    random.setText(String.valueOf(random));
    int sum= randomNumbers++; //not sure what your intent is here, you assign sum the value of randomNumbers, then increment randomNumbers?
    sumRandomNumbers += randomNumbers; //add this random number to sum
    //sumRandom.setText(String.valueOf(sum)); //why?
    sumRandom.setText(String.valueOf(sumRandomNumbers)); //display sum
}
```